# Using multiple router in express

Tags: node.js, express

I've applied the routes to my application like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

  //localhost:8080/api/story
router.get('/story', function(req, res){
    res.send('welcome to our story');
})

  //localhost:8080/api
app.use('/api', router); 

  //localhost:8080/user/02213
router.get('/user/:id', function(req , res){ 
  console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

`localhost:8080/user/02213` not working at the moment. Do I need to create a new router instead or?

Comment: you are doing wrong you should do localhost:8000/api/user/02213 as this route is attached with router

Comment: ...`console.log( req.params.id );` , use req.params to get values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a new router, because `router` will only be used for requests that start with `/api`:

```
//localhost:8080/api/story
router.get('/story', function(req, res){
  res.send('welcome to our story');
})

//localhost:8080/api
app.use('/api', router); 

//localhost:8080/user/02213
var anotherRouter = express.Router();
anotherRouter.get('/user/:id', function(req , res){ 
  console.log(req.params.id);
  res.end();
});
app.use('/', anotherRouter);
```

Comment: I understand, would it be better to keep them in their own file?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable.

Comment: In that case, how it can communicate (pulling and pushing) with mongodb? Because i created a model in server.js file.

Comment: @SahinErbay that's really quite a different topic, but generally, models are also created in their own separate file and exported to other parts of the app. Perhaps this question, and its answer, may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966854/structure-of-express-mongoose-app

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id` not recognized in the request,
You should call it like that : `req.params.id`